# Does programming to an interface allow you to not recompile your code?

Tags: c#, oop, interface

Just a general question does programming to an interface allow your code not to recompile. We just need to deploy the changes and no need to recompile the whole application, right?

If we need to recompile whole application how does interface help in term of loose coupling of modules in your system?

Comment: How do you compile your application? Does all _your_ code compile into a single exe or dll?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a site for asking specific questions for trouble spots in your coding. If you've already [searched](https://stackoverflow.com/search) the site, [compose a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) with [enough explanation and code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that the folks who are trying to help you can see what you've tried, understand it, and reproduce your error.

Comment: Compilers already do it for you. If you are looking for look at if a file has been modified,  then apply a checksum to the file and compare it with the previous checksum. But only with a checksum you don't know if the program has the same instructions (code) than the previous version. You need a parser to find this changes.

Answer (score 1):

Not automatically, but it may if you structure the projects correctly.

Consider the following types, each in their own project, and the following dependencies

- MyApplication depends on everything
- IMyInterface depends on nothing
- MyClass depends on IMyInterface
- MyImplementation depends on IMyInterface (and implements IMyInterface)

Now MyApplication can create a MyImplementation object and give it to MyClass. However, since MyClass does not depend on MyImplementation directly it does not need to be recompiled if MyImplementation change. Only if IMyInterface changes. At least if you are using incremental compiles. More realistically you would probably have an IOC container that does all the object construction for you.

You can view the dependency graph of the projects as a directed a cyclic graph. If anything in a project changes everything that depends on it, directly or indirectly needs to be changed. Build times could be optimized if you could reduce the dependencies on the code that changes most frequently. But you should also consider that c# compiles rather fast overall, and build-times are affected by many other factors.

This assumes the projects are part of the same solution, for assembly references or dynamically loaded dlls other rules apply.

Comment: My idea was trying to minimize the impact of changes of the whole project to prevent recompiling. Now i understand it is based on the dependency graph of my project. For the IOC container i can try playing with the lifetime of the injection.

Answer (score 0):

No, when changes are made to an exe, or a dll, or even an external dll, then the dll has to be recompiled.

If we are talking about the main exe with an external dll which is used, then only the DLL would have to be recompiled, but it still needs to replace an existing dll which was originally *linked* with the exe. (Think *drop in plugin type dll*)

---

Years ago I had a C#/.Net VSTO smart document which would load Dlls from a shared *trusted* location on the Companies intranet. The user only had to install the smart document once.

Then when I would make changes to the business logic, then I would replace new dlls in the share and tell the user to restart the smart document which would load the external dlls.

Comment: From a design principle perspective, using interface allow lose coupling between modules or systems. How is it loosely couple when all the modules have to be recompiled?

Comment: Use the drop in plugin dll as an example again. If the *solid* instance which adheres to the interface in that drop in plugin is changed, the dll has to be compiled into IL code so the exe can read it in at runtime; but the exe doesn't change. Are you confusing re-use with loose-coupling. Loose-coupling doesn't have anything to do with how dlls and exe's work together. If you have an exe which instantiates a solid instance that adheres to a interface, and one changes the interface, that affects the solid instance in the exe and the whole thing has to be re-compiled because it sits in an exe.

Comment: Look into the factory pattern for Loose Coupling...by having the factory return a versioned interface **instance**, that makes it *loosely coupled* from the clients that get that instance. Hence the client doesn't have to instantiate the instance; hence it does not know about it and is uncoupled.